# An experiment to understand better what HTTP status codes do

Tags: python, http, browser, http-status-codes

### Server setup and browser checking

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class customHTTPServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('<HTML><body>Get!</body></HTML>')
        return

server = HTTPServer(('',8080),customHTTPServer)
print 'server started at port 8080'
server.serve_forever()
```

Now when I go to `http://localhost:8080` with my browser I can see the expected `Get!`.

### Unexpected observations

**Test 1**:

Now I tested using different status codes in my server. I tried these status codes: `301`, `302`, `400`, `402`, `403`, `404`, `405`, `406`, `407`, `408`, `418`, `500`, `501`, `502`, `504`, `505` and `511`.

**(Q1) Strangely when using different status codes(except for `407`) I get the same behavior as I was using status code `200`. Why is that?**

**Test 2**

Secondly I replaced `self.wfile.write('<HTML><body>Get!</body></HTML>')`
with `self.wfile.write('')` for all the different status codes I tested in the 1st test. When I used status code `403`, `404`, `500`, `501`, `502`, `504` or `505` I now got a specific browser message on the browser (`403 Forbidden`, `404 not found`, ...).

**(Q2) Why do I only receive specific browser messages using these status codes but while not using the other ones?**

**Summary**

I can distinquish 3 types of behavior:

- Using status code `301`, `302`, `400`, `402`, `405`, `406`, `408`, `418` or `511` has
  no difference with using status code `200` regardless if I am sending an empty or non-empty string.
- Using status code `403`, `404`, `500`, `501`, `502`, `504` or `505` will create a specific browser message on the browser but only when an empty string is
  sent.
- Using status code `407` returns a specific browser message(showing a `323` error) regardless if I am sending an empty or non-empty string.

Comment: HTTP status codes themselves do *absolutely nothing*. The client has to interpret the status and handle it. See [List of HTTP status codes](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) on Wikipedia for the expected behaviour.

Comment: Which browser are you using?  What tools are you using to confirm that you are properly connecting to your server and not something else that may exist on that port?

Comment: I used Chrome. Well, I changed the status code and saw the same behavior repeatedly. I am pretty sure there is nothing else served through that port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(A1) When you send error codes but return a body anyways, the browser will assume it is a custom error page sent by your webserver. This is the way that for example stackoverflow gives you a [custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/notfound) for requests of unknown documents, instead of the default browserpage for 404.

(A2) Check the meaning of the statuscodes in which no browser message is displayed and ask yourself if it's sensible to show a browser message when they are returned. Also, most likely, it will differ from browser to browser when messages are displayed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Take 404 Not Found as an example.  Sites will often generate a custom 404 page which includes some means of site navigation.  This can be more helpful than an error message generated by the browser.  So if the server returns content with 404, the browser displays it.

It also allows more information about the specific error.  E.g. 403 Forbidden might provide information about why access to a resource is restricted, or how to apply for access permissions.

It's no big surprise if you read the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616); it defines which status codes can include bodies and which can't (like 204 No Content :).

Note that if you used a different UA such as wget, you might notice that it handles 404 responses differently.